Azure Functions: what are valid @BindingNames?
I have a trigger:
public class BlobTriggerJava {
    @FunctionName("BlobTriggerJava")
    @StorageAccount("AZURE_STORAGE")
    public void run(
            @BlobTrigger(name = "copyfrom", path = "funcblobcontainer/{name}") String content,
            @BindingName("name") String fileName,
            @BlobOutput(name = "pasteTo", path = "pastehere/{name}") OutputBinding<String> pasteTo,
            final ExecutionContext context) {
        pasteTo.setValue(content);
        context.getLogger().info("FileName: " + fileName + " is coptied! --> Content is: " + content );
    }
}

By having this parameter @BindingName("name") String fileName, I can get the blob's name... But what else can I use instead of name? Is there a list with the options?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings#supported-bindings

Thanks for the insights @RuiJarimba.
You can also use other metadata properties in @Bindingname() instead of name.
Below mentioned metadata properties are used for the Azure Blob storage trigger:

path:  The path to the triggering blob.
uri:  The blob's URI for the primary location.
properties: The blob's system properties.
metadata:  The user-defined metadata for the blob.

Use below code to get the URI of the triggering blob, you can use the following code:
public class BlobTriggerJava {
    @FunctionName("BlobTriggerJava")
    @StorageAccount("AZURE_STORAGE")
    public void run(
            @BlobTrigger(name = "blob1", path = "funcblobcontainer/{name}") String content,
            @BindingName("uri") String uri,
            @BlobOutput(name = "blob2", path = "pastehere/{name}") OutputBinding<String> pasteTo,
            final ExecutionContext context) {
        context.getLogger().info("Blob URI is: "+uri );
    }
}


Thanks, is there a documentation where these properties are listed?
